# Getting zero(0) in paypal response?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I have just tried to integrate paypal payment gateway in my site.
for that I have followed all the steps which are showed in guideline, I could payment and it shows me successful payment message, I went my account and there also I could see the payment transaction info.but in paypal response (post array)
I got zero(0) instead of data.

for that first of all I have made a developer account in paypal,
then through I have created one business and one buyer account.

here is my code

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="21" readonly="" id="qty-1-amt">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="21">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="harsh-business@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Mobile">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Test Item Number">

        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

        <!-- Specify URLs -->
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://paymentgateway.alphansotech.com/buyproducts">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://alphansotech.com/response.php">
        <ul>
            <li>Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" id="qty-1"> </li>
            <li><strong>Total: </strong>$ <span id="qty-1-span">21</span></li>
            <!--<li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy"/></li>-->
            <li> <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
                <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif"></li>
        </ul>
        </form>
```

Comment: You have to set IPN as well in your request.

Comment: I don't think the question is about IPNs. However, the question is somewhat unclear. Are you saying PayPal does a $21 transaction but calls it a $0 transaction somewhere? Or are you saying that you expect some return parameters in the redirect after payment but there are no such variables? If the latter, read the docs on the "rm" parameter. By default (rm unspecified, as in your form) PayPal puts variables in the GET params, not the POST params.

Comment: @geewiz the transaction was correct and I got also the detail about transaction correct.but when it is redirected to my return url, I am getting 0, in place of data , my code at return url is **var_dump($_POST)** here I want array of data which come through paypal response

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments above, you are looking for the data in the wrong place. You are looking in $_POST, whereas by default PayPal puts the return values in $_GET. You need to do one of two things. Either:

1) Change your code from using $_POST to $_GET, or

2) send PayPal the value rm=2 (") to request that PayPal move these return variables from GET parameters to POST parameters. This is documented here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have tried to dump data by GET method, It worked ,but I did not get the data which exactly I want,It shows me the 1 (payment success) in place of 0 which was in post method,but I need all data which I have sent such as quantity,name etc.. I have considered this example http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/payment-system-with-paypal.html

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong :). You should be storing the cart details yourself, usually in a session linked to a cookie and/or in a database, and passing a unique ID to PayPal in the invoice_id field (you can pass the full cart information to PayPal also, but PayPal uses this to display cart info to the user in the UI, not all those fields are pass-through). Then you get the cart back from the session/database, using invoice_id if necessary for the database lookup.